# gmaps4rails having trouble rendering custom marker images

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I have 4 types of markers on my map and I am loading an image for each point depending on it's "school type". This is working fine but I'm getting a weird artifact on the map that I don't get when using the standard marker image.

```
def map
    @json = School.where(:disabled => [false, nil]).to_gmaps4rails do |school, marker|
      marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "schools/marker", :locals => { :object => school })
      if school.school_type_id == 1
        marker.picture({ "picture" => view_context.image_path('map_icons/blue_P.png'),"width" =>  '20',"height" => '34'})
      elsif school.school_type_id == 2
        marker.picture({ "picture" => view_context.image_path('map_icons/red_C.png'),"width" =>  '20',"height" => '34'})
      elsif school.school_type_id == 3
        marker.picture({ "picture" => view_context.image_path('map_icons/yellow_J.png'),"width" =>  '20',"height" => '34'})
      elsif school.school_type_id == 4
        marker.picture({ "picture" => view_context.image_path('map_icons/green_I.png'),"width" =>  '20',"height" => '34'})
      end

      marker.json({ :id => school.id })
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @schools }
    end
  end
```

Images of the artifact:

http://foa-approved.org/map_artifact1.png

http://foa-approved.org/map_artifact2.png

I am using the css fix for the map controls:

```
.map_container img {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Can this fix work on the marker image or it is something else entirely?

Comment: @apneadiving Can you take a look at this?

Comment: I guess there is some css issue. Sorry but I don't know how to fix. I'm very curious if you find out.